# Investigating the numerical accuracy of a truncated Legendre polynomial expansion of an unknown function

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, legendre-polynomials

I have an integral equation involving an unknown function $f(x)$, of the most basic form

$$
\int_{-1}^{1} e^{iω(t) x} f(x) \ dx = g(t)
$$

I am solving for an approximation of $f(x)$ by substituting in its truncated Legendre expansion, $f(x) \approx \sum^N a_j P_j(x)$. Then, the integral equation reduces to a product of the sum coefficients $a_j$ and the Fourier transforms of the Legendre polynomials (expressed in closed form using Bessel functions). That is,

$$
\sum^N a_j \hat P_j(ω(t)) = g(t)
$$

The sum coefficients are found by collocating in the free variable $t$ and solving the resulting linear system.

Since $f(x)$ is unknown, how can I investigate the accuracy of the computed $a_j$ versus their actual value, and also the rate of convergence? This method is unlike a traditional finite difference method, or traditional Legendre interpolation, so I am unsure of what kind of literature to look for.

Edit for extra info: Since the coefficients themselves are also approximate, the final computed approximation for $f(x)$ is $\sum^N \tilde a_j P_j(x)$, where $\tilde a_j$ are approximated values of $a_j$. So, in a sense, there are 2 approximations happening here, one for the truncation of the sum and one for the evaluation of the sum coefficients. Which one is more important to study?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is $\omega(t)$? It you can take $t$ values that $\omega(t) = k \pi$, then you get the Fourier series automatically.

Comment: @Yimin $ω(t)$ are some predetermined values based on the other restrictions present in the problem so unfortunately is not free to be set at $kπ$. How would that help with getting accuracy and error bounds?

Comment: If you are free to take $\omega(t)$, then you can get an explicit $f$ in Fourier series, if you only have a predefined values for $\omega(t)$, then it possibly falls into something related to non-uniform Fourier transform, which can compute $f$ based on its Fourier coefficients (but not at integer frequency). Anyway, that is just one of the approaches. I believe using Legendre polynomials should also work, the convergence might just differ by a small factor in $N$, like $\sqrt{N}$.

Comment: When $f$ is analytic on $[-1, 1]$ and can be extended to the Berstein ellipse, I think you can find the error using the truncation. For instance, if $f= \sum_{j} c_j P_j(x)$ with true coefficients $c_j$, and a truncation to $N$ terms, the error can be found in many papers, roughly at an order of $\sqrt{N}e^{-cN}$ if my memory is not wrong. Then you need to estimate the error in your computed coefficients $a_n - c_n$, that is actually depending on a linear system now, the RHS is the remainder, which is super small. The error will be bounded by some condition number multiply that remainder.